# Facebook Graph API /me/Feed V2.4 vs V2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-feed

I'm trying to access all feeds a facebook user using the Graph API .

However I'm getting quite different responses from V2.3 to V2.4 .

In version 2.4 using the instruction / me / Feed not receive complete information of the posts just returns some fields , while in the previous version had access to all the information. As can be seen the difference in the following answers.

V2.4

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "message": "A brincar com o Xico Zé.. ;)",
      "created_time": "2015-07-11T18:23:59+0000",
      "id": "10153293007088673_120153297333223673"
    },
    {
      "message": "Ana Simões e Pedro Simões este é que é bom para a Liliana Assunção..",
      "story": "Diogo Lopes shared Classic Hits 4FM's video.",
      "created_time": "2015-07-11T14:20:59+0000",
      "id": "10153293007088673_1360153296966998673"
    }
],
  "paging": {
    . . .
  }
}
```

V2.3

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10153129496378673_120153297333223673",
      "from": {
        "name": "Diogo Lopes",
        "id": "10153129496378673"
      },
      "message": "A brincar com o Xico Zé.. ;)",
      "picture": "",
      "link": "",
      "name": "Diogo Lopes on Instagram: “A brincar com o Xico Zé.. ;)”",
      "caption": "Diogo Lopes on Instagram: “A brincar com o Xico Zé.. ;)”",
      "description": "A brincar com o Xico Zé.. ;)",
      "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/post.gif",
      "actions": [
. . .
      ],
      "privacy": {
        "value": "ALL_FRIENDS",
        "description": "Your friends",
        "friends": "",
        "allow": "",
        "deny": ""
      },
      "type": "photo",
      "status_type": "added_photos",
      "object_id": "120153297333233673",
      "application": {
        ". . ."
      },
      "created_time": "2015-07-11T18:23:59+0000",
      "updated_time": "2015-07-12T20:50:19+0000",
      "is_hidden": false,
      "subscribed": true,
      "is_expired": false,
      "likes": {
        . . .
        ],
        "paging": {
          . . .
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
         . . .
        ],
        "paging": {
          . . .
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "10153129496378673_1360153296966998673",
      "from": {
        "name": "Diogo Lopes",
        "id": "10153129496378673"
      },
      "to": {
        . . .      },
      "message": "………....",
      "message_tags": {
. . .
      },
      "story": "Diogo Lopes shared Classic Hits 4FM's video.",
      "story_tags": {
        "0": [
          {
            "id": "10153129496378673",
            "name": "Diogo Lopes",
            "type": "user",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 11
          }
        ],
        "19": [
          {
            "id": "125659037470226",
            "name": "Classic Hits 4FM",
            "type": "page",
            "offset": 19,
            "length": 16
          }
        ],
        "38": [
          {
            "id": "874724002563722",
            "name": "",
            "offset": 38,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      "picture": "https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xta1/v/t15.0-10/s130x130/11331624_874724179230371_2123630990_n.jpg?oh=701da51ed6690c70ba8d3e7ba5cbb58c&oe=56273FFC&__gda__=1448812275_e37392fe85f01402fa0565b0086df710",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/ClassicHits4FM/videos/874724002563722/",
      "source": "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xtp1/v/t42.1790-2/11656282_889978921061393_14476072_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjQ4NCwicmxhIjo1MTJ9&rl=484&vabr=269&oh=a4e7e8ec985cf5374082e5c9639d5b06&oe=55A5ED2C",
      "name": "Classic Hits 4FM",
      "description": "A Giant Nope!!!

Would you go on this Swiss Ride?",
      "actions": [
. . .
      ],
      "privacy": {
        "value": "EVERYONE",
        "description": "Public",
        "friends": "",
        "allow": "",
        "deny": ""
      },
      "type": "video",
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
      "created_time": "2015-07-11T14:20:59+0000",
      "updated_time": "2015-07-11T21:28:06+0000",
      "is_hidden": false,
      "subscribed": true,
      "is_expired": false,
      "likes": {
        . . .
        ],
        "paging": { . . . }
      },
      "comments": {
}
…
}
```

Someone can help me know how I can get a similar response in V2.4 to V2.3??

Obs. My facebook aplication have ***user_posts*** Permission.

Comment: The first thing you should do in such a case, is consult the changelog – and of course there this is explicitly mentioned: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the upgrade in Graph API i.e. version 2.4. You have to specifically pass a `fields` parameter with the relevant keyword of which, data you would like to retrieve.

Please refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post) document of Facebook Developers

> Changes from v2.3 to v2.4
>
> Declarative Fields
>
> To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in
>   v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for
>   your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes
>   likes and comments by default, but GET
>   /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more
>   details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

An example of v2.4:

```
<page_id>/feed?fields=id,message,picture,likes,shares,comments
```

Comment: Do you know if this will this still work with the older versions? I have multiple sites using the same plugin I wrote for the facebook feed, but some have 2.2 while a couple newer ones have 2.4. If I change the code, I don't want it to explode all my old sites. Obviously I can write more code to handle the different versions, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to. Hah

Comment: It'll still work if you are using a 2.3 or earlier access_token and use /feed without passing fields. However if it's a 2.4 access_token you need the fields parameters. The 2.2 will expire March 25 2017. You can see when the api version will expire here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: V2.3 expired on July 10 2017