# FB API GRAPH: why I can't catch the user email?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to retreive the email of a user logging into my web app; here's my code:

```
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response.name + ', ' + response.email);
  });
```

the user name is correct, but email results as

> undefined

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have they allowed to show email?

Comment: I don't know how to ask the authorization to get information, as soon as the log in my app

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390197/facebook-graph-api-me-feed-v2-4-vs-v2-3

Comment: _“Where am I going wrong?”_ - you neglected to ask for the fields you want returned, so that you only get the few default ones (id and name, for the user endpoint.)

Comment: oh, i missed that you don´t even ask for the email. updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v3.2

Ask for the `email` permission in the login process:

```
FB.login((response) => {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Also, you need to ask for the fields you want to get:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response.name + ', ' + response.email);
});
```

Make sure the user even has an Email, it´s not required. And make sure you actually get asked for the `email` permission in the login popup.

Side Note: I would just use `console.log(response)`, so you can see the whole object instead of some `undefined` values.

Comment: Now it works: the problem was that I didn't ask for the fields